# What's the mythological boss monster from The Battle of the Labyrinth?

Tags: percy-jackson, rick-riordan

I have been listening to the Battle of the Labyrinth by Rick Riordan on audiobook. There is big boss monster that's like a kind of dragon with animal heads around her waist, whose name sounds like 'Kom-pay' in the version I was listening to. Percy Jackson meets her in Alcatraz about a third of the way into the book when she is guarding Briarus, and she is also part of the assault on the camp near the end of the book.

I am familiar with a number of different creatures from Greek mythology but I can't place this one, and because I only have the pronunciation from the audiobook I can't search for it online. I have looked through a couple of lists of monsters from Greek myth online and can't find this one with a name stating with K or Ch.

How do you spell the name of this creature, and which monster from Greek mythology does it refer to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In *Percy Jackson*, it's spelled "Kampê", but it's also spelled with a "C", Campe. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campe?wprov=sfla1) gives this as its overview:

> In Greek mythology, Campe or Kampe (/ˈkæmpiː/; Greek: Κάμπη) was a female monster. She was the guard, in Tartarus, of the Cyclopes and Hecatoncheires, whom Uranus had imprisoned there. When it was prophesied to Zeus that he would be victorious in the Titanomachy—the great war against the Titans—with the help of Campe's prisoners, he killed Campe, freeing the Cyclopes and Hecatoncheires, who then helped Zeus defeat Cronus.

Later on, Wikipedia has this description:

> According to Nonnus, Zeus, with his thunderbolt, destroyed:
>
> > highheaded Campe ... for all the many crooked shapes of her whole body. A thousand crawlers from her viperish feet, spitting poison afar, were fanning Enyo to a flame, a mass of misshapen coils. Round her neck flowered fifty various heads of wild beasts : some roared with lion's heads like the grim face of the riddling Sphinx; others were spluttering foam from the tusks of wild boars; her countenance was the very image of Scylla with a marshalled regiment of thronging dog's heads. Doubleshaped, she appeared a woman to the middle of her body, with clusters of poison-spitting serpents for hair. Her giant form, from the chest to the parting-point of the thighs, was covered all over with a bastard shape of hard sea-monsters' scales. The claws of her wide-scattering hands were curved like a crooktalon sickle. From her neck over her terrible shoulders, with tail raised high over her throat, a scorpion with an icy sting sharp-whetted crawled and coiled upon itself. Such was manifoldshaped Campe as she rose writhing, and flew roaming about earth and air and briny deep, and flapping a couple of dusky wings, rousing tempests and arming gales, that blackwinged nymphe of Tartaros: from her eyelids a flickering flame belched out far-travelling sparks.

..which more or less seems to be how Rick describes her in the books.